# Facing accuracy issue with sentence transformers

Tags: python-3.x, sentence-similarity, sentence-transformers

I'm facing issue in sentence similarity while using sentence transformers with cosine metric. I'm comparing transcribed audio text with the predefined set of sentences. Even when the the whole sentence in predefined set exists in the transcribed text, the accuracy is low.

The accuracy must be highly positive when the compared sentences matches but not getting accuracy. Maybe because the transcribed text is long comparing to existing text, hence, more different text also. So, anyone can help solving that issue?

Thanks in advance...

Here's the code:

```
        for rs in red_section:
        for s in split:
            logging.info(f'{s} " --vs-- " {rs}')
            # score = sentence_similarity_model.get_score(sentence, rs, metric="cosine")
            sentences = [rs, s]
            embeddings = sent_model.encode([rs, s], convert_to_tensor=True)
            cosine_scores = util.cos_sim(embeddings, embeddings)
            pairs = []
            for i in range(len(cosine_scores) - 1):
                for j in range(i + 1, len(cosine_scores)):
                    pairs.append({'index': [i, j], 'score': cosine_scores[i][j]})

            pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)

            for pair in pairs[0:10]:
                i, j = pair['index']
                logging.info(f'{sentences[i]} --vs-- {sentences[j]}')
                score = round(pair["score"].item() * 100)
            logging.info(f'Score --> {score} %')

            if score >= 80:
                logging.info(f"Red Confidence in similarity -> {round(score * 100)} %")

    for ys in yellow_section:
        for s in split:
            logging.info(f'{s} " --vs-- " {ys}')
            # score = sentence_similarity_model.get_score(sentence, ys, metric="cosine")
            sentences = [ys, s]
            embeddings = sent_model.encode([ys, s], convert_to_tensor=True)
            cosine_scores = util.cos_sim(embeddings, embeddings)
            pairs = []
            for i in range(len(cosine_scores) - 1):
                for j in range(i + 1, len(cosine_scores)):
                    pairs.append({'index': [i, j], 'score': cosine_scores[i][j]})

            pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)

            for pair in pairs[0:10]:
                i, j = pair['index']
                logging.info(f'{sentences[i]} --vs-- {sentences[j]}')
                score = round(pair["score"].item() * 100)
            logging.info(f'Score --> {score} %')

            if score >= 80:
                logging.info(f"Yellow Confidence in similarity -> {score} %")

    for gs in green_section:
        for s in split:
            logging.info(f'{s} " --vs-- " {gs}')
            # score = sentence_similarity_model.get_score(sentence, gs, metric="cosine")
            sentences = [gs, s]
            embeddings = sent_model.encode([gs, s], convert_to_tensor=True)
            cosine_scores = util.cos_sim(embeddings, embeddings)
            pairs = []
            for i in range(len(cosine_scores) - 1):
                for j in range(i + 1, len(cosine_scores)):
                    pairs.append({'index': [i, j], 'score': cosine_scores[i][j]})

            pairs = sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: x['score'], reverse=True)
            logging.info(f'Pairsssssss --> {pairs}')

            for pair in pairs[0:10]:
                logging.info(f'Pairrrrrr --> {pair}')
                i, j = pair['index']
                logging.info(f'{sentences[i]} --vs-- {sentences[j]}')
                score = round(pair["score"].item() * 100)
            logging.info(f'Score --> {score} %')

            if score >= 80:
                logging.info(f"Green Confidence in similarity -> {score} %")
```

Comment: Are you comparing the audio signals, or are you doing speech-to-text and looking for words?  Do you have code to show us?

Comment: I'm using speech to text @TimRoberts. I have update the question with the code.

Comment: Can you tell us what modules you are using?  I'm not sure where `sent_model.encode` and `utli.cos_sim` come from.

Comment: I've initialized sentence transformers in sent_model. So, encode is the method of sentence transformers. util is also class of sentence transformers. Sorry, I can't share more code as this is my work code. @TimRoberts

Comment: OK, but you haven't told us a single thing about which tools and libraries you are using.  If this is all home-grown code, then there's nothing we can help you with.

Comment: I've already said in the question that I've used sentence transformers, sorry if I'm seem rude, do you even read the question properly? @TimRoberts.

Comment: I read it properly.  You didn't write it properly.  "Sentence transformers" is a generic predicate phrase, not a Python module.  The module is `SentenceTransformers` or `sentence_transformers`.  It's best not to be rude to people offering you free advice.

Comment: Hey @TimRoberts, I thought machine learning needs training about understanding the meaning of sentences not the actual people. But I guess, I was wrong. Thanks for your help anyways. I figured it by myself. :)

Comment: I forgot one thing to say "Sentence transformers" is not a generic predicate phrase, if you search for that on Google, you are gonna get the reference of the library itself. I thought the person who is gonna answer smart, not like you. @TimRoberts